# Why have I been down voted for asking how nested variable types change time complexity?

Tags: discussion, questions

Why has [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584778/how-do-nested-variable-types-change-time-complexity) been down voted so quickly?

I'm asking if nesting variables in a list then performing operations on them would change the complexity from [Python's Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

Comment: Without knowing any python, the question looks rather broad and unresearched.

Comment: It reads like a no-effort homework question:(

Comment: it also poses 2 questions at once, generally frowned on

Comment: As an aside:  I think it's fair to ask why one was getting voted down as it seems like they're trying to improve or understand what it is they did wrong.  This is a great teaching opportunity around what we expect a question on Stack Overflow to be like.

Comment: Your question is downvoted because it is nonsense. You link to the official documentation which states the time complexity for list operations, and then ask "how do those operations change when I do X". The answer is, they don't, there's no reason why they should, and if they did, that would be documented on the very page you link to. Furthermore, the question demonstrates that you have no idea how a list works, as it internally only contains pointers to its elements and thus doesn't know or care if the contained element is a 2-element list or a 10^9 element list or something else entirely.

Comment: Why didn't you just try it before you asked the question?

Comment: I did try it and noticed about 1% difference in time for all data sizes. I'm using a recursive function and was going through a process of elimination. This part of the Wiki made me ask "If you need to add/remove at both ends, consider using a collections.deque instead." I didn't study CS, I started studying on my own when I created my SE account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few reasons for issuing a downvote on this question.

- It reads like a homework type question. While not forbidden, the way you have it worded looks like it's been copy/pasted from an instructor's assignment. Generally this indicates a lack of research on the part of the asker.
- You pose two questions. At a glance, this makes it look like a rather broad question.
- You don't state what you've tried. You do state what you are worried about (negating the O(1) advantage), but have you tried anything to test your questions? Throw together a short script showing your concerns (ie. "When I do this, it appears that I've lost my O(1)..."). By showing your code, you help us to understand your concerns. It may be a flaw in your logic, it may be a misunderstanding of how certain aspects of a language work, but it helps us know exactly what you are asking.

---

#### How can you improve this in the future?

Pose a single question at a time. When you do, provide a little more than one line of code so that we can better understand your question. Words are good. Code is good. Both is better.

If this was a real question, and not a homework question, work on your phrasing a bit. The way it is worded comes across as a question an instructor would pose to a student.

Comment: I disagree with your answer. The question isn't broad because it contains two subquestions, but because OP seems to have no idea what they're doing (which in turn indicates a lack of research and missing basics). Also, it doesn't really feel like homework as it's complete nonsense - any teacher giving such a homework question should be fired. Stating what they tried would also not be helpful because the question would still be nonsense. All in all, I do not think any rewording or code would have resulted in a better question - the question itself is simply bad, rewording can't change that.